# Find Replace text FOO with Style "Heading 1" with <h1>Foo</h1>

Tags: html, css, styles, find-replace, word-2016

I am trying to find an easy way to convert my Word documents to HTML without the awful save-as that is built in.  These are structured documents (designed for our screen-reader (JAWS) users), and so they use Heading 1, 2, 3, 4 & the Table of Contents.

We plan to convert these to DAISY audiobooks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAISY_Digital_Talking_Book ) , so we need pretty clean, but structured, HTML to convert.

I tried the find-replace, using Styles, but it would just replace anything in the text part of the search.  I could *convert* it from any one style to another, but adding text in the box messed it up.

(I think I see that CSS for DAISY means that instead of just `<h2>` it will have to be `<level2 class=='section' <h2>` and closing tags), but that's step 2 after I handle this part.)

I just want to be able to find any text using Style 2 and add text to the start of that line saying "yep, here's some style 2" so that I can do the HTML/CSS stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple Find/Replace. For example, specify the Heading 1 Style for the Find parameter and use:

```
Replace = <h1>^&</h1>
```

For a macro you could incorporate that into, see: [Convert a Word Range to a String with HTML tags in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524539/convert-a-word-range-to-a-string-with-html-tags-in-vba/54225552#54225552)